# unable to create multiple div inside div dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

```
$.post("../../Handler/Topic.ashx", 
       { commentclob: commentClob, 
         commenttitle: commentTitle,
         topicId: id, 
         Button: buttoname },
       function (data) {
         obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('commentbox');

         $table.append('<tr><td>' + 
                       'Comment Id:' + 
                       obj.CommentId + 
                       '</td></tr>');

        var includeReply = "<input type='button' 
                                   class='btnReply' 
                                   value='Reply' 
                                   id='btnReply-" + obj.CommentId + "' />";


        $("#commentContainer").prepend(
          $('<div/>').attr('id', '#comment-' + obj.CommentId)
                     .append($table)
        );

        //This doesnt work         
        $("#comment-" + obj.CommentId).append(
          $('<div/>').attr('id', '#container-' + obj.CommentId)      
                     .append(includeReply)
        );
});
```

html

```
  <div id="commentContainer"></div>
```

I am successfully able to append div with #comment-id to comment-container but I am unable to append another div inside #comment-id.

I have tried

```
               var str = $("<div>").attr("id", "#container-" + obj.CommentId)
               $(str).append(includeReply);
               $table.append('<tr><td>' + 'CommentDiv:' + str + '</td></tr>');
```

But it gives

CommentDiv:[object object]

Comment: Are you seeing any clues in your error/debug console?

Comment: Yes, it's because you're trying to concatenate a DOM node with a string. It might be a string of HTML, but it's still a string. Example: [works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2x4F7/1/). [Doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2x4F7/). I'd suggest creating the `tr` and the `td` the same way you created the `div`. And then append them together as appropriate. [That seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2x4F7/2/).

Comment: can u tell me how to create button dymaically so that i can append to div

Comment: my suggestion is use http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/ easy to manage and modify

Comment: how to create td and tr the same way...can u give example

Comment: `var newTd = $('<td />');` assign the attributes using `attr()`, as you are above. It's the same way you're already doing it in your code example. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is an HTML object so it can concatenated like that. You have to extract the markup with `.html()` and then concatenate it.

```
   var str = $("<div>").attr("id", "#container-" + obj.CommentId)
   $(str).append(includeReply);
   $table.append('<tr><td>' + 'CommentDiv:' + str.html() + '</td></tr>');
```